# AB Testing Analysis in R. prop.test() OR t.test()

Tags: r, prop, t-test

**AB Testing Scenario:** Testing a new design of REGISTRATION PAGE ENTRY BUTTON on web - the user clicking on the BUTTON will be taken to a new page where in which the user can supply the email and create a registered account.

The Sample is chosen randomly - 50% see the TEST BUTTON, 50% see the CONTROL.  The Data is collected at the user-level.

**Columns:** account_id,
         group ( values test or control),
         visit_flag (values 1 if visited, 0 if didn't)

Should I be using the prop.test to check if the CTR (click-through-rate) is significant or should I be using t.test?

Comment: Outcome is binary (click-through or not) which suggests that a prop.test might be reasonable first choice.

Comment: Thank you. I also came to that conclusion by researching online.